# Whenever I use absolute positioning to vertically center, the entire nav disappears

Tags: html, css, sass

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333333;
    position: relative;
    li {
        height: auto;
        width: 20%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        a {
            display: block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    }
    .float-left {
        float: left;
        font: 2em bold sans-serif;
    }
}
```

Here is my html for context. I added another div just to test out vertical centering on a different element and it works fine. But I couldn't keep the li's on the nav from disappearing whenever I give them absolute positioning. Sorry it's in sass.

```
    <ul>
        <li class="float-left"><a href="">Michael Thomas</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">R&eacute;sum&eacute;</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with your ul li elements? Give us pictorial representation.

Answer (score 1):

When the "li"s are inline/relative, they force the parent "ul" to take the dimensions of the child elements. But when you change the "li"s to position absolute, the "li"s no longer force the parent "ul" to take encompass the shape of its content, so the parent "ul" has a height and width of zero. If you removed the "overflow:hidden" on the parent I think you'd still see its contents.  I think you need to give your nav/ul a height and width.